# Using ImportXML to import a table in google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import the table of values found at this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180108121529/https://transportation.triboard.ca/Cancellations.aspx)

I have used this formula:

```
=importxml("https://web.archive.org/web/20180108121529/https://transportation.triboard.ca/Cancellations.aspx",
"//td [style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top]")")
```

But I get a formula parse error.

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification? In this modification, `https://web.archive.org/web/20180108121529/https://transportation.triboard.ca/Cancellations.aspx` is put in a cell "A1".

#### Modification points:

- Enclose `padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top` by the single quote.
- Remove one `")`.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top']")
```

#### Another pattern:

As an another pattern, how about this formula? This also retrieves the table. But the format is different from above one.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//tr[./td[@style='padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top']]")
```

If I misunderstand your question, I apologize.